# Test anonymous class in Junit or Groovy/Spock test

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, ejb, spock

I am trying to write units tests in Groovy/Spock and have to test the below code.

```
public class ClassA {
    @Inject
    private ClassB classB;

    @Inject
    private ClassC classC;

    @Inject
    private ClassD classD;

    public void update(final int a, final Map<String, Object> b) {
        classB.executeCommand(classC.callToMethodInClassC(), new InterfaceE<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void execute() {
                classD.update(a, b);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now when I write test code I am unable to reach `classD.update(a, b);` line. I know how to inject mocks/real object for ClassB, ClassC, ClassD, but unable to reach that statement. Please help.

**Note:** `ClassA.update()` & `ClassD.update()` have no relation between them except that their signatures match.

Comment: A few questions to clarify your use case. 1) Do you mock `classB` or do you use a real implementation? 2) Is the `executeCommand` an asynchronous or synchronous method? If you mock `classB`, then your method does nothing - it executes empty mock. If you use a real object and the method is asynchronous you might need to use some await mechanism so your test method does not finish before completing the async call. That's all I can tell you based on what I see in your example. It misses a lot of context and details and we can only guess.

Comment: Apologies from coming back late. (1) I can mock ClassB given Imy unit test can reach ```classD.update(a, b);``` (2) Async, lastly, I couldn't understand what you meant in last but one statement. Also, if you need more details, please mention that. I'll try to provide the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your classB mock like this:

```
Mock(ClassB) {
    executeCommand(_, _) >> { c, e -> e.execute() }
}
```

I.e. provide a mock implementation for the `executeCommand` method of ClassB that actually calls the `execute` method of interfaceE.

EDIT: full working example:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class TestMeSpec extends Specification {

    def "my test"() {
        def b = Mock( ClassB ) {
            executeCommand( _, _ ) >> { c, e -> e.execute() }
        }
        def c = Mock( ClassC )
        def d = Mock( ClassD )

        def a = new ClassA( classB: b, classC: c, classD: d )

        when:
        a.update( 0, [ : ] )

        then:
        1 * d.update( 0, [ : ] )
    }
}

class ClassA {
    ClassB classB
    ClassC classC
    ClassD classD

    void update( final int a, final Map<String, Object> b ) {
        classB.executeCommand( classC.callToMethodInClassC(), new InterfaceE<Void>() {
            @Override
            Void execute() {
                classD.update( a, b )
            }
        } )
    }
}

class ClassB {
    void executeCommand( c, InterfaceE e ) {
        println "REAL CLASS B executCommand() METHOD RUNNING"
    }
}

class ClassC {
    def callToMethodInClassC() {}
}

class ClassD {
    void update( a, b ) {
        println "REAL CLASS D update() method called with $a and $b"
    }
}

interface InterfaceE<T> {
    T execute()
}
```

Comment: Apologies for coming back late. But how do I refer "e" here when e belongs to an anonymous instance of an interface. If I create a new instance locally, then the flow will go through that and not through the actual code.

Comment: Your test code calls `classA.update()`, which calls `classB.executeCommand()`, passing two args to it, the second of which is an instance of `InterfaceE`. Now, `classB` is a Mock, so the mock's `executeCommand` method is what gets called, and as I've shown above, you can provide a lambda (as the fake implementation of that method) that takes the args and does something wiht them, in this example, call `execute()` on the provided instance of `InterfaceE`.